# Parametric - equations: Solving an equation

Tags: coordinate-systems, parametric

**Question**

A curve is given by parametric equations $x=qt+2$ and $y=t^3 + q$, where $q$ is a constant.
The $y$-intercept of the curve is at $\left ( 0,\frac{617}{25} \right )$.
Find the value(s) of $q$ and hence state the parametric equations.

**Solution**

$x=qt+2$   $\hspace{2.6cm}$ **[1]**

$y=t^3 + q$  $\hspace{2.7cm}$   **[2]**

From **[1]**,

$\Rightarrow t=\frac{x-2}{q}$  $\hspace{2.5cm}$  **[3]**

Substituting **[3]** into **[2]** gives

$\ y=\left ( \frac{x-2}{q} \right )^3 +q$  $\hspace{1.4cm}$  **[4]**

The curve crosses the $y$-axis when $x=0$, so substituting $x=0$ and $y=\frac{617}{25}$ into **[4]** gives

$\frac{617}{25}=\frac{-8}{q^3}+q$

I want to know what is the easiest way to solve this equation?

Comment: How would you feel about a numerical solution? Would it suffice?

Comment: @Matti P. I am not sure if I understand your comment. Are you suggesting I try different values of q until I find a value(s) of q that satisfies the equation?

Comment: Not necessarily. What I'm really asking, is "Does the problem require an exact solution?" Because if the answer is no, you could just use some method of your liking (for example, Wolfram Alpha) and say that the answer is $q\approx 24.6781$ or $q\approx -0.68073$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B617%7D%7B25%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B-8%7D%7Bq%5E3%7D%2Bq

Comment: @Matti P. The values of q you mentioned match the values given in the answers section of the book from which the question I asked is from. However, I can't see the step by step solution in Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Is a step-by-step solution required? One such could be: Draw the graph of
$$
f(x) = \frac{617}{25} - \frac{-8}{x^3}-x
$$
and see where the graph intersects with the $x$-axis.